# How to load and display a blender .obj source file scene using Qt 3D libraries

Tags: c++, qt, blender, qt3d

I'm trying to load a .obj source file from blender, and display it, *LibertStatue.obj* is the .obj file which is located in the same folder as the main.cpp file below. When I run this code, I get blank window which I think is supposed to show a statue of liberty, and a command prompt that says **QObject::connect(opneglcontext, unknown) Invalid nullptr parameter**.
I'm using Qt Creator on linux Xubuntu.

I downloaded the .obj file of statue of liberty from here : https://free3d.com/3d-model/statue-of-liberty-73656.html.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QPhongMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QOrbitCameraController>
#include <Qt3DRender>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QUrl data = QUrl::fromLocalFile("LibertStatue.obj");
    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *flyingwedge = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    material->setDiffuse(QColor(254, 254, 254));

    Qt3DRender::QMesh *flyingwedgeMesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh;
    flyingwedgeMesh->setMeshName("FlyingWedge");
    flyingwedgeMesh->setSource(data);
    flyingwedge->addComponent(flyingwedgeMesh);
    flyingwedge->addComponent(material);

    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view.camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(40.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 40.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DRender::QPointLight *light = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);
    light->setColor("white");
    light->setIntensity(0.8f);
    lightEntity->addComponent(light);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lightEntity);
    lightTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(60, 0, 40.0f));
    lightEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);

    Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(rootEntity);
    camController->setCamera(camera);

    view.setRootEntity(rootEntity);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say when going step by step?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis
When I go step by step, I get the **QOject::connect...**
 error when I execute this line
`Qt3DCore::QEntity *flyingwedge = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `setMeshName` call. The documentation for the `QMesh` C++ class is misleading: `setMeshName` is not for setting a name to the `QMesh` object, but for selecting which geometry from the OBJ file you want to load. Its actual behavior is explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-mesh.html) of the corresponding QML type.

So you have two options: just remove the `setMeshName` call, or pass the actual name of the geometry, which you can find out by opening the OBJ file with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting your code it looks to me that the Qt3Dwindow cannot be displayed standalone and the creation of a window container is needed to display the Qt3DWindow inside of a Widget (QFrame).

A typical Qt3D application I use for testing looks as follows:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>

#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCameraLens>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QOrbitCameraController>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QDiffuseSpecularMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QSphereMesh>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto view = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow();

    auto rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    view->setRootEntity(rootEntity);

    auto camera = view->camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 1., 0.1f, 10000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 5));
    camera->setUpVector(QVector3D(0, 1, 0));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    auto camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(rootEntity);
    camController->setCamera(camera);

    auto sphereMat = new Qt3DExtras::QDiffuseSpecularMaterial;
    sphereMat->setDiffuse(QColor(Qt::blue));

    auto mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh();
    mesh->setRadius(1);

    auto sphereEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(mesh);
    sphereEntity->addComponent(sphereMat);

    auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);
    QFrame frame;
    frame.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    frame.layout()->addWidget(container);
    frame.resize(QSize(400, 300));

    QTimer::singleShot(100, [&]() {
        camera->viewAll();
    });

    frame.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```